# Sitefinity - remove and merge duplicated list items

Tags: c#, asp.net, sitefinity, sitefinity-6.x

The users of our Sitefinity site made a lots of duplicated items in the lists (ie. the "Product type" dropdown list containts "*Great quality*" and "*Great q.*").

We should remove "*Great q.*" from the list BUT to do this we need change all "*Great q.*" to "*Great quality*".

This is a recurring problem so we need to create a module or widget to help users to handle it from time to time.

Comment: What exactly is your question and what have you tried so far? 

If you change "Great q." to "Great quality" then you would have two identical items "Great quality" - maybe you just need to *delete* the wrong item?

Comment: Yes, it's correct, I need to delete the wrong item. But until the wrong item is used in any other entities, it's cannot be deleted.

Comment: And these items are of type List (Content > Lists), correct? 
If so, what do you mean they cannot be deleted?

Comment: If I'm not wrong then I cant delete an item from a list until it's referenced from an entity. It's like foreign key constraints in the database.